# Wp Pagenavi how to display all results

Tags: plugins, pages, pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi, paginate-links

I'm using Wp Pagenavi Plugin. I'm trying to display all results from a button.

I'm using this:

```
$out .= '<form action="" id="showall" method="POST" name="results">
<input type="hidden" name="woocommerce-sort-by-columns" id="woocommerce-sort-by-columns" class="sortby" value="100"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="All">
</form>';
```

It's working if I'm on the first page, but if I'm on another page (second one / third one..), it gives me the 404 Error message.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear how is this code connects to plugin. Is your problem with link being generated? Or with content of the page on the link? What the page contains precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced it with:

```
$out .= $instance->get_single( 1, 'first', "All", 100, 1 );
```

And I changed the get_single function, more exactly I added a parameter, "all", and this one won't afect anything else.

```
function get_single( $page, $class, $raw_text, $format = '%PAGE_NUMBER%', $all = 0 ) {
    if ( empty( $raw_text ) )
        return '';

    $text = str_replace( $format, number_format_i18n( $page ), $raw_text );
            if($all == 1) return "<a href='" . esc_url( $this->get_url( $page ) ) . "?all-products=1' class='$class'>$text</a>";
    else return "<a href='" . esc_url( $this->get_url( $page ) ) . "' class='$class'>$text</a>";
}
```

Finally, I added this to the end of the functions.php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['all-products'])) 
   add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 100;' ), 20 );
```

In my case, when the button "All" is pressed, the website will display the first page of the category, with 100 products. You should change 100 to your desired number.

I believe it's not the best solution for this problem, but it's certainly working for me.